# Eclipse - sorting members on save

Tags: java, eclipse

I like eclipse **save actions** feature, but I can't get rid of one little annoying thing. I use sorting members and methods on save.

The good thing is, eclipse moves member/method to correct position, alphabetically.

The bad thing is, when I am writing method and save it, eclipse moves method **but not current caret position**. So basically, I press CTRL+S and end somehwere at completely other place then I was before, so I have to scroll up/down to find new location of my method.

Is there some kind of workaround?

I am using Eclipse 3.6 Helios atm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like a bug, try submitting it to eclipse at [this site](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/).
As a workaround - but not the best one, you can use **Ctrl-O** to find the method.
2 more workaround options:

- Set a `//TODO return here` in the line that you want to return to, then you can filter the task view by a specific todo.
- Put breakpoint before saving.

Generally I prefer not to use options like this, since when working with other poeple in a large scale project, it can cause a lot of *noise*. I mean that if you make a change to an existing file, then save it and then the format happen. next step you will commit this file to the repository. when someone or even you try to look at the diff of the change, it will be cluttered with all the formatting and sorting. So I prefer doing it as an independent change.

Comment: +1 about noise. Definitely don't use an option like this automatically  in a team environment without team agreement/policy. It can render diffs useless trying to separate a real change from a formating/reordering change.

Comment: In this case I believe it is better to have naturaly sorted members - by access level and by alphabet even in team project. CTRL+O is quite nice, I'll try submiting as you proposed.

Comment: I didn't say order doesn't matter in a team. just do it separately from any code modification.

Comment: Okay this really is eclipse bug. It's been marked as duplicate of very old (2005) bug. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=84087